# Comparing 2 values in the Same column

Tags: sql

I have a table like following :

```
  Orderserialno SKU  Units
  1234-6789     2x3   5
  1234-6789     4x5   7
  1334-8905     4x5   2
  1334-8905     6x10  2
```

I need to get the count of distinct orderserialno where Units are not equal within a orderserialno. There could be more combinations of Sku's in an order than what I have mentioned but the eventual goal is to get those orders where units corresponding to various SKUs (in that order) are not equal.

In the above case I should get answer as 1 as orderserialno 1234-6789 has different units.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is a relatively simple `GROUP BY` query:

```
SELECT Orderserialno, Units
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY Orderserialno, Units
HAVING COUNT(1) > 1
```

This would give you all pairs `(Orderserialno, Units)`. To project out the `Units`, nest this query inside a `DISTINCT`, like this:

```
SELECT DICTINCT(Orderserialno) FROM (
    SELECT Orderserialno, Units
    FROM MyTable
    GROUP BY Orderserialno, Units
    HAVING COUNT(1) > 1
)
```

If you need only the total count of `Orderserialno`s with multiple units, replace `DICTINCT(Orderserialno)` with `COUNT(DICTINCT Orderserialno)`.

Answer (score 0):

To get the list of such order numbers, use an aggregation query:

```
select OrderSerialNo
from t
group by OrderSerialNo
having min(Units) <> max(Units)
```

This uses a trick to see if the `units` value changes.  You can use `count(distinct)`, but that usually incurs a performance overhead.  Instead, just compare the minimum and maximum values.  If they are different, then the value is not constant.

To get the count, use this as a subquery:

```
select count(*)
from (select OrderSerialNo
      from t
      group by OrderSerialNo
      having min(Units) <> max(Units)
     ) t
```